# Javascript - How to call any function with a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, function, call

I want to know how to call a function with a string value

In some other questions i found this: `window["functionName"](arguments);`,
and i assume is not working cause my functions are not global, and i don't want them to be global.

I have an example here:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var testing,
    showMe;

    testing = function(){
        alert('Working');
    };

    showMe = function(test){
        window[test](arguments);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        showMe('testing');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see, what i want is call the function, `testing()` using just a String value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window` is an object. You can place it inside an arbitrary object:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    "use strict";
    var testing,
    showMe,
    funcs = {};

    funcs.testing = function(){
        alert('Working');
    };

    showMe = function(test){
        funcs[test](arguments);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        showMe('testing');
    });
})(jQuery);
```